# Computer can not connect to any shares

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, domain, ping

Windows 7 64 bit

After rebooting my computer i can not access any shares at all.The error is "windows cannot access \tb228dc\" There are shares on the domain i can usually connect to. I can not connect to other computers shares or the shares on the domain controller. The weird thing is they can connect to the shares on this computer. I can ping every computer, im on the internet on this computer. Everything works except the shares, this doesn't make sense!

I have tried updating drivers, re adding the computer to the domain, disabling all start up items, disabled symantec endpoint.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the "net use" command run from the command line?

Comment: well now i cant connect to this computer from other ones, anyways when i try to map a drive with net use i get "system error 67 has occurred The network name cannot be found"

Comment: Forgot to mention i am using windows 7 64 bit, but this has worked for about 6 months flawlessly, only after that restart it stopped working. I haven't made any adjustments to registry or anything since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i had to resort to system restore. It actually works somewhat in windows 7